# How to make the mat-select validation work?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-validation

My code is resided in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybblf9).

A popup modal will be popup when the button is pressed.

My problem is the "System" drop-down box validation does not work, that mean the error message does not show when I click the "System" drop-down box , and then click somewhere in the popup modal.

I have another drop-down box validation sample which is working properly in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzw2nk).

Would you tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CallTreeManualContactMapping.ts` of your not working example you got

```
export class CallTreeManualContactMapping {
  division: string;
  callTreeId = -1;
}
```

But in the one that is working you got

```
export class CallTreeManualContactMapping {
  division: string;
  systemName: string;
  callTreeId:number;
}
```

Personally, when I change the file like this it works.